# Preparing a library .jar for release with Maven and Git

Tags: java, git, maven, open-source, release

Suppose I have a project (`myproject` - a library that builds into a .jar file) that builds happily using Maven and that I am version controlling using Git.

It has a relatively simple `pom.xml` with a couple of external dependencies, all of which are available at the Maven Central repo.

Everything is working fine in development, and now I'm happy with `myproject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and want to make it into a proper release so that I can put it into a public (open source) Maven repository and let people use my wonderful new library. In particular, I want to make it as easy as possible for people to use my library with minimal effort or potential for confusion.

What are the recommended steps / checklist for making this release?

Any pitfalls / mistakes to avoid?

Comment: Please attach source to your artifact and compile with debug information.  That will make it much nicer to use in a debug session, especially one where you need to figure out how exactly your code works (for a workaround or finding out why a parameter is not right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy would be using maven release plugin.
You can read about it 
[here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/)

In general It can be used to release your project (it manages versions, uses some VSC maniplations, for example, I used it with SVN and it created SVN tags for me). It also enforces that you don't have dependencies on 'SNAPSHOT' versions of jar, otherwise you won't be reproduce your build and so on. At the end it uploads your artifact to the repository.

I don't know much about permissions you need to upload everything into the central maven repository, I've used it for our private repository...

Hope this helps